# Cache HTML string or DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, memory-management

I'm developing a file manager type of app in javascript. I do ajax requests to get contents of a directory and I was thinking to cache this into a variable, just in case the user navigates to a different directory, then comes back (so I don't have to request the list again). But what should I store in the variable? The HTML element objects or the HTML string? Which uses less browser memory?

Comment: k thx, ooxxooXoXXx :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose you to store JavaScript objects only. I don't think it takes much time to render your HTML nodes. But nodes themselves are rather heavy objects. Storing HTML string doesn't make sense at all as browser still has to parse it to DOM nodes. So it'll be equal to storing JS objects.

Also it's much harder to manage DOM nodes in sense of memory management. It's very easy to forget to detach events handlers to to null-ify references to nodes. So, IMHO, it's easier to clean up DOM nodes completely and utilize them than manage all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, speaking, a string would use less browser memory.

However I would *always* advise caching the DOM elements instead of the strings.  HTML should only be used for getting content from a server, and not for client side manipulation.

Reattaching a detached set of DOM nodes will be near instantaneous, and those nodes can still have additional data and event handlers attached that would be lost if the nodes had been serialised into HTML and then deserialised back again.